# How to use the -> in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this php construct mean: $html->redirect(“URL”)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234196/what-does-this-php-construct-mean-html-redirecturl)

Hi, I've been looking for what this operator "->" does, but I can't seem to find a reference to it, only people using it in come and I can't make out what its doing, an explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: *(reference)* See [`T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` in List of Parser Tokens](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)

Answer (score 3):

The `->` is used with object methods/properties, example:

```
class foo{
  function bar(){
    echo 'Hello World';
  }
}

$obj = new foo;
$obj->bar(); // Hello World
```

More Info:

- http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Answer (score 2):

It's for classes.

See here:

http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: More specifically: it's for class *instances*.

Answer (score 2):

-> operator access properties and methods of an object.

Probably you should read PHP OOP introduction: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on sarfraz's answer to demonstrate how to access properties:

```
class foo{
  public $value = "test"; 
  function bar(){
     //// code
  }
}

$obj = new foo;
$obj->bar();
echo $obj->value;     //displays "test"
```

Comment: would this be the same as saying bar($value)?

Comment: No... bar($value) is not really useful without having $object=new foo(); and calling $obj-bar() which is a method, whereas $value is a member/field of the class.